# Global Variable over Layers on MVC API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging

We are building a MVC API + Entity project, right now we are creating our log layer, we wanna log every single entity that we add, alter or delete, however we need to log the user id that is performing the action as well, the id is provided with the Header [Authorization].

Our log is performed as the action previous to the database action, because of that we would need to add the user id to every method signature on all layers until the DAL.

After researching a bit on the internet, looking at Global Variables, HTTPContext, etc,  we did not find any solution that did not "harm" the project layers, any ideias ? How should we proceed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use DI to inject the current user into whatever DAL classes need it.  For example, I use Ninject to do this so I don't need to have the user id as a parameter on every update function:

```
kernel.Bind<IPrincipal>().ToMethod(c => HttpContext.Current.User);
```

Then in whatever classes in the app need it:

```
[Inject]
public IPrincipal CurrentUser { get; set; }
```

Comment: Following your answer i found Unity also, i am going to implement both and see what helps me the most, thanks